# how to use polymorphism with provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I try to use Polymorphism with the Provider package in Dart/Flutter, but I'm not sure if it is possible or not and if I have made a mistake.

I have two provider class "Provider1" and "Provider2" which extend an abstract class "AbstactProvider", I have a widget "WidgetProvider1Or2"
which need to interact with Provider1 Or Provider2 but flutter throw me a "ProviderNotFoundException".

thanks for yours help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc_concept/cubit/counter_cubit.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

abstract class AbstactProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  void printName();
}

class Provider1 extends AbstactProvider {
  @override
  void printName() {
    print("Provider1");
  }
}

class Provider2 extends AbstactProvider {
  @override
  void printName() {
    print("Provider2");
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CounterCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widgetProvider1 = ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => Provider1(),
      child: WidgetProvider1(),
    );
    Widget widgetProvider2 = ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => Provider2(),
      child: WidgetProvider2(),
    );
    Widget widgetProvider1Or2 = ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => Provider1(),
      child: WidgetProvider1Or2(),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [widgetProvider1, widgetProvider2, widgetProvider1Or2],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class WidgetProvider1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetProvider1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.watch<Provider1>();
    return Container();
  }
}

class WidgetProvider2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetProvider2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.watch<Provider2>();
    return Container();
  }
}

class WidgetProvider1Or2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetProvider1Or2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.watch<AbstactProvider>();
    return Container();
  }
}
```